# Banner - is there a built-in view?

Tags: android, view, material-design, android-view

Is there an existing `View` in `Android` for a [banner](https://material.io/design/components/banners.html)? Or do I need to build one myself using the [specs](https://material.io/design/components/banners.html#specs)?
To be clear, this is not for ads but for the `Material-Design` concept of `Banner`.

Comment: Interesting question. They made a `Snackbar` component, but I know nothing of a Banner!

Comment: Looks like as per today you'll have to do it yourself - same page, further down: [Implementation](https://material.io/design/components/banners.html#implementation) status "planned" except for Flutter

Comment: @Vucko I know! They made `Dialog` as well (well, you do need to change the style).

Comment: @0X0nosugar true, I missed that...

Answer (score 0):

You should build your activity layout to show a banner using TextView and Buttons. There is no banner component.

Personally, I prefer using [Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/training/snackbar/) messages for actions

Comment: `Snackbar` has only one action whereas `Banner` has (or should have) two. Also, the [usage](https://material.io/design/components/banners.html#usage) is different: `Snackbar` should be self-dismissing and banner requires user dismissal.

Comment: Material-design is just a guide. You can do things different, it's only to put people in the right way for a good UI.

Answer (score 0):

There are unofficial implementations available:

https://github.com/sergivonavi/MaterialBanner

https://github.com/cesarferreira/MaterialComponent.Banner